# How to run API and how to input the data in API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, express

I am trying to make an API for filtering and sorting of school data according to its location and fees using NodeJS, ExpressJS and MongoDB.

So, its main base is:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const apiRouter = require('./Routes/router');

const port = 4003;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/schooldata',
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
).then(success => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server started at port ${port}`);
    });

}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Then I made school_data model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schoolSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city_id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    location_id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    country_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    fees: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('schools', schoolSchema, 'school');
```

Then the Controller Part:

```
const schools = require('../Models/schoolData');

exports.getfilter = (req, res) => {
    const location_id = req.body.location_id;
    const city_id = req.body.city_id;
    const cost = req.body.cost;

    schools.find({
        city_id: city_id,
        location_id: location_id
    }).sort({
        min_fees: cost,
        max_fees: cost
    }).then(result => {
        location_id = result,
        city_id = result,
        min_fees = result,
        max_fees = result
    }).catch(error => {
        message = error;
    })
}
```

Then I Routed the API:

```
const express = require('express');
const schoolController = require('../Controllers/schoolData.js');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/schoolFilter',schoolController.getfilter);

module.exports = router;
```

So, if I start NPM and link it in postman i.e. Link ('http://localhost:4003/api/schoolFilter'), no response is shown. Also, how can I input data according to the user. Eg. if user selected location_id: Mumbai and min_fees: 40000 then that filtering and sorting must shown.
So, send any ideas if possible... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never told it to send a response - you need to call a response method like `send`, `render`, `sendFile`, `json` etc.
As for sorting and filtering, it seems like you are already doing that...
Also, quick code optimization tips:

1. change

```js
schools.find({
        city_id: city_id,
        location_id: location_id
    })
```

to the cleaner DRY-friendly

```js
schools.find({
        city_id,
        location_id
    })
```

using EcmaScript 6 techniques
2) Use `camelCase`, i.e. capitalize the first letter of each word after the first one for better readability.
Summary: call a response method and try to optimize your code